# Precise Definition of a Limit and Limit Points

Tags: real-analysis

On page 116 of Real Analysis by Stoll, it states that in the definition of a limit: "as $x \rightarrow p$ ... with $p$ a limit point of the domain"... and some other stuff.

I am wondering, why it is necessary that $p$ be a limit point of the domain? It seems like this has to do with the way in which continuity is described in the domain, but I have not been introduced to such a concept.

I feel as if I understand the exact definition of a limit, besides the fact that $p$ is a limit point of the domain.

Comment: What does domain mean in this context?

Comment: If $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a real valued function with $D \subset \mathbb{R}$. So, a limit point $p \in D$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are saying is that he is trying to define the limit of a function. If this is the case, then it continues to say something along the lines of $x_n\rightarrow p$ with $p$ a limit point of the domain, then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(x_n)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow p} f(x)$. If this is the case, then it must be necessary that $p$ is a limit point in the domain, or we do not have a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ for which we can evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)$. Note, $p$ does not need to be an element of the domain. It only needs to be a limit point of the domain. Furthermore, some texts do not include sequences for which $x_n=p$, because the idea is that we need not have $p$ to consider the above mentioned limit.